# Send push notification to clients with Kinvey from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mobile, push-notification, delphi-xe6, kinvey

I have done the client side push notification application, with Kinvey backend, but I would like to send push notifications automatically from another Delphi application I am developing.

- How to send push notifications to the mobile clients from Delphi application with Kinvey backend ?

Comment: Hi, I also looked for this - It seems that Embarcadero only added receiving a push notification in their BAAS components - I think you'll have to talk to Kinvey directly VIA REST - check it here http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/push#top  *** I'm using Appmethod not XE5/6 but I don't think it's there either as I trailed XE6 for the one month***

Comment: Hello. I am not finding there where is the actual sending of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there have to be defined custom endpoint business logic function, which to handle the incomming requests, and send them to the appropriate Kinvey API.

This part seems to be handled by the component "BackendPush" and the endpoint function have to be placed as a name in "KinveyProvider" property "PushEndpoint".